# How can I access the Google+ hangout chat?

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

I want to implement a speaker queue manager that works off of the chat - see GitHub repo [Q Bot](https://github.com/mhausenblas/q-bot) for more details - but are unable to find a way to listen to chat events (and then react to them). Any hints?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no way to access chat from the Hangouts API.

There is, however, an [open feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=29) for this. If you star the issue you'll be notified when it's updated.

You might be able to work around this by making your own interface in a Hangout extension to control the inputs for this app, rather than overloading the chat feature.